# modify external css value using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i try to separte all css and js value in external file and called it to the html but it say

> model.js:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: modal is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.onclick (model.js:15)

how can i fix it

Comment: You need to show us the code which **doesn't** work, not the code which does.

Comment: Please try and reformat your description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you added your external JS file in the head. This will fire the JS before the DOM is ready with loading. So there is no modal to select, because it hasn't been rendered yet by the browser.

Here are three possible solutions.

**1. Relocate your external script**
A simple solution is to relocate the script tag, which loads the external recourse, to just before closing the body tag.

```
      // Your HTML markup
    <script src="yourfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**2. window.onload**
Wrap your code into a function and fire it with `window.onload`.
`window.onload` waits for everything, from stylesheets to images, to load. So downside to this is when something like an image is still loading, the modal won't fire, while most of the page seems fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/e6zqp0p0/

**3. jQuery solution**
Add jquery and wrap your code between the document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Your code here
});
```

Comment: What solution did you try? (I might not have been clear that I provided three possible solutions)

Comment: the second one solution

Comment: Where are you loading your model.js? Between the `<head>` tags?

Comment: If you're inserting it before the closing body tag it should've worked without the `window.onload` function. Could you update your question with the entire html and the entire js of the two separate files?